# composer require iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes is not installing on laravel 5.8.35

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When i am trying to install this package iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes via the command 
`composer require iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes` . It is giving me this error

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes ^2.0 -> satisfiable by iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes[2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes 2.0.0 requires illuminate/events ^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4].
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - don't install illuminate/events v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.35, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.35].
```

can somebody please help me, what to do now? i am stuck, find solutions on net but nothing is working.

I want this package to use softdelete functionality on parent child concept in laravel.

Here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "brian2694/laravel-toastr": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "*",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "*",
        "thestringler-laravel/manipulator": "*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "*",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "*",
        "mockery/mockery": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
        "symfony/css-selector": "*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "app/Models"
        ],
        "files": [
          "app/Http/Helper/helper.php",
          "app/Http/Helper/logActivities.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of this package (`2.0.0`) is a Laravel 6 package. Version `1.5.0` seems to be the Laravel 5 package you want. Since you didn't specify a version to install, composer uses the latest version.

Install `1.5.0` via `composer` using

```
composer require iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes "1.5.0"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you were correct...i just updated my laravel framework to 6.0.0 and now this package has installed correctly.

````- Installing iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes (2.0.0): Downloading (100%)   ````